# Best way to expose a simple API from Android

Tags: android

I'm completely new to Android programming. I researched this topic all morning and couldn't find an answer.

What I need to do is to write an Android app (preferably some kind of background service) that will expose a simple API (just a couple of functions taking and returning strings). This app (background service) will use uiautomator API to get information from a target, 3rd party app running in the foreground.

Could you please give me some pointers on how to implement this?

This is for an internal system, and will only receive a couple of calls per minute.

Specifically I have 2 questions:
  - How to implement a background service to interact with the foreground running app
  - How to expose de API to other devices across the network

I found some http server articles so I know that would be 1 possible way, but I'm wondering if that's overkill and there are simpler solutions.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html)... and forget about background services.

Comment: I think the right term for you question is not API